# Replace type mismatch (numeric to string)

Tags: stata

I want to create a new variable  in Stata `age_cat` based on `age`. My code:

```
gen age_cat = age
replace age_cat = "Adult" if age>18 | "0-5 years" if age >=0 & age<=5 | "6-11 years" if age>=6 & age<=11 | "12-18 years" if age>=12 & age<=18
```

I'm getting a type mismatch error:

```
type mismatch
r(109);
```

How do I fix this? I know `encode` will work for string to numeric replace. Is there a way to do this the other way around?

Comment: `encode` is not for string to numeric replace; it is for generating new variables. It's sometimes but not always the right thing to do if you have a string variable and want a numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate error is simple. You copied `age` to `age_cat` so `age_cat` is evidently a numeric variable, just like `age`. You then tried to `replace` it with string values. That's a `type mismatch` and Stata bailed out.

Alternatively, if `age` is really a string variable, then comparing it with numeric values such as `18` is also a `type mismatch`.

The rest of your syntax would have failed any way. The logical operator `|` (or) can be used to separate input conditions. It can never be used to separate different results.

Here is a slow way to do what you want, assuming `age` is numeric:

```
gen age_cat =  "Adult" if inrange(age, 19, .) 
replace age_cat = "12-18 years" if inrange(age, 12, 18)
replace age_cat = "6-11 years" if inrange(age, 6, 11) 
replace age_cat = "0-5 years" if inrange(age, 0, 5)
```

I've added code such that missing ages, which count as more than 18, will not get classified as `Adult`.

Here's another way to do it:

```
gen age_cat = cond(age > 18, "Adult", cond(age >= 12, "12-18 years", cond(age >= 6, "6-11 years", "0-5 years))) if age < .
```

where I have made a trap for missing values explicit. `cond()` is the equivalent of `ifelse()` in various languages. See also [this tutorial](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0016) if you want more detail.

There is also `recode`, which appeals to many people.

Comment: Have always been a nested `cond` (or some `egen` function) over a `recode` guy myself